# We are one, single, far different from the rest

Tags: riddle, knowledge

We are one, not single, far different from the rest

We can regenerate from battles in a sort of nest

We can adapt, assimilate, use it for the best;

We live in this galaxy, but in a quadrant, far far away

**So can you guess this place I stay?
And what I am that I say?**

**Extra:**

If you're so smart, who was taken away from us and reunited back at their original home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are

> The [Borg](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Borg), from Star Trek

We are one, not single, far different from the rest

> The Borg are a collective entity. Usually, a single Borg drone has no true sense of self.

We can regenerate from battles in a sort of nest

> Borg ships are large cubes, which contain [repair stations](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_alcove) that look like alcoves in a hive. The mechanical parts of Borg can easily be fixed and enhanced after being damaged.

We can adapt, assimilate, use it for the best;

> The Borg mission is to assimilate all organic life into their collective.

We live in this galaxy, but in a quadrant, far far away

> The Borg originate from somewhere in the [Delta quadrant](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Delta_Quadrant).

So can you guess this place I stay? And what I am that I say?

> You are from the Delta quadrant, and are either in the Borg mothership or in a traveling Borg cube. You are [Locutus](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Locutus) and you speak for the Borg.

If you're so smart, who was taken away from us and reunited back at their original home?

> If it's not Locutus (Picard), Data, or Hugh, then you are probably referring to [Seven of Nine](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Seven_of_Nine). She was actively rescued from the Borg by the Federation, and was returned back to her original home in the Alpha Quadrant.

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone I modified my answer after your latest edit.

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone Yes, that is much more specific. Fourth time's the charm.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> **the Borg** from Star Trek.

> We are one, not single, far different from the rest

> The Borg is a collective made of many individuals sharing a single consciousness, hence indeed 'We are one" while also "not single".  They are the only humanoids portrayed on Star Trek that have this trait, so are different from the rest.

> We can regenerate from battles in a sort of nest

> We see Borg do this exactly.

> We can adapt, assimilate, use it for the best;

> The Borg famously ***assimilate*** other species, incorporating their best features and distinctiveness into themselves to further improve themselves.

> We live in this galaxy, but in a quadrant, far far away

> The Borg are from the Delta Quadrant, part of our galaxy but very distant from Earth.

> So can you guess this place I stay? And what I am that I say?

> Not sure what you're looking for with "this place I stay"; perhaps you're looking for either Delta Quadrant or a Borg Cube.  And of course already have said what you are.

> If you're so smart, who was taken away, and sent back home from my people, just to stay?

> Captain Jean-Luc Picard was captured by the Borg (taken away) and for a time was Locutus, of Borg.  He was eventually returned to the Enterprise and deBorgified.
>  You may also be talking about **Hugh**, a Borg who was rescued from a crashed ship and taken aboard the Enterprise for a time, forcibly disconnected from the Collective.  Eventually, Hugh was returned to his crashed ship and rejoined the Borg.

.